# On Mozilla how to select the element outside of the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click the outside area of the form, the form will disappear.
I implement this functionality on Chrome.

```
$(window).on("click", function(e) {
    if( !$(event.target).closest('#login_form').length && !$(event.target).closest('#popup_btn').length ) {
        $("#login_form").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#popup_btn").fadeIn("slow");
        $(".nk-header-table").attr("id", "");
    }
});
```

but it doesn't work on Mozilla.
because of the **closest()** method, I think.
How can I handle it?

Comment: Why are you using `$.fn.closest` on DOM elements identified by an ID?  To my knowledge, since they're globally unique(in best practice) you should be accessing them directly, with more universal results across browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `e.target` instead of `event.target`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.